# I can't open .EDMX files in the Entity Data Model designer

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I can't find the ADO.NET Entity Data Model in Visual Studio 2012. When I open EDMX it opens in XML only not in designer. When trying to add new item to a project I don't find ADO.NET under Data tab.

I tried almost all solutions proposed on the net but no result:

- I removed EF5 and installed EF 6.2 but the problem persist.
- I tried to install VS2012 Updates but no change.
- Repairing current install no change.
- I tried to find `ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu.msi` in the install media but can't find it.    -

I tried all other solutions but not working.

Comment: That is weird. Reinstall VS12 is probably your next option

Answer (score 4):

I've figured out the problem : when i run ETool.msi from Install Media for repair, 
it was an older ver. (EF.4) than the currently installed ver. (EF.6) so it wasn't working.

So i downloaded EFTool ver.6 (same ver. of installed EF) ,run Repair command and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but perhaps in reverse.  I uninstalled VS 2012, reinstalled and when I opened up my v4 EF model it opened in XML rather than the designer.

I uninstalled the EF Designer for VS from the Control Panel, ran EFTools.msi from the installation media and everything was fine.

Perhaps a version compatibility issue like Hussein's.

Answer (score 0):

you should add both EntityFrameWork.dll and EntityFrameWork.SqlServer.dll to your project